# Delphi XE2 component for rollover menu

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe2, popupmenu

In my application (Delphi Xe2) I have 'multichoice' button (ie 'Export' Button have 'Export to PDF' and 'Export to XLS' choices).
I need to get a menu, like that of the popup menu to appear when I move the mouse over a button (or panel or other object). This menu needs to appear just under the button and needs to be a "VCL Stylable" component.
I tried a TPopUpMenu but it is not convenient to Hide.
I may also considere to show the menu with the OnClick event instead of OnEnter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `TButton` with its style set to `bsSplitButton`, together with a `TPopupActionBar` that's set to the button's [`DropDownMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.DropDownMenu) property. The menu drops down when you click the right *split* having the down arrow. Available for Vista and later only..

For earlier OS something like the below can be employed:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Pt := ClientToScreen(Point((Sender as TButton).Left, (Sender as TButton).Top));
  PopupActionBar1.Popup(Pt.X, Pt.Y + (Sender as TButton).Height);
end;
```